# How can I change the font in axis labels of special characters to Calibri (or calibri Like Fronts)?

Tags: r

I would like to create the following plot.

```
plankton_tow <- data.frame(DO <- c(-1.2, -0.8, -0.5, -1.5), depth = c(10, 20, 30, 40))
core_tops <- data.frame(DO <- c(-2.0, -1.6, -1.3, -2.5), depth = c(50, 60, 70, 80))

plankton_tow$depth <- max(plankton_tow$depth) - plankton_tow$depth
core_tops$depth <- max(core_tops$depth) - core_tops$depth


par(pty = "s")  


plot(plankton_tow$DO, plankton_tow$depth, xlim = range(c(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO)), ylim = c(0, max(plankton_tow$depth, core_tops$depth)),
     xlab = expression(delta^18*O ~ "[‰] vs. PDB"), ylab = "Depth (m below sea level)", main = "Plankton Tow vs Core Tops",
     pch = 16, col = "blue", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
points(core_tops$DO, core_tops$depth, pch = 16, col = "red")

axis(side = 1, at = seq(min(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO), max(plankton_tow$DO, core_tops$DO), by = 0.5))
axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, max(plankton_tow$depth, core_tops$depth), by = 10), labels = rev(seq(0, max(plankton_tow$depth, core_tops$depth), by = 10)))
```

I want the axis titles to be in calibri but I have the problem that the delta and promill characters should also be in calibri.

I generally use par(family = "Calibri"), but this solution has no idea how to deal with the special characters.

Comment: It will be much easier for people to offer relevant help if you can make this question reproducible, by using a standard data set or including some sample data (as code, please). If the core of the question is about the font of a label, most of this seems extraneous.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to post this :C sorry

Comment: I Updated it! Sorry for this one :D